# running a shell script from another script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a script in unix that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc  -osign sign.c

./sign < /usr/share/dict/words | sort | squash > out
```

Whenever I try to run this script it gives me an error saying that squash is not a valid command. squash is a shell script stored in the same directory as this script and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -f squash.awk
```

I have execute permissions set correctly but for some reason it doesn't run.  Is there something else I have to do to make it able to run like shown? I am rather new to scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `squash` → `./squash`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in @Biffen's comment, unless `.` is in your `$PATH` variable, you need to specify `./squash` for the same reason you need to specify `./sign`.

When parsing a bare word on the command line, bash checks all the directories listed in `$PATH` to see if said word is an executable file living inside any of them.  Unless `.` is in `$PATH`, bash won't find `squash`.

To avoid this problem, you can tell bash not to go looking for `squash` by giving bash the complete path to it, namely `./squash`.